# What happens when a user taps map in Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm developing a Apple Watch app but I'm not one of the lucky guys who got the watch earlier. It says that when a user taps a map it opens the native maps app.

**When I place a red marker on the static map, will it be displayed in the native maps app as well?**

I think there is no way to directly start a navigation from the watch app but if anybody knows how this - pretty common - use case can be handled I would be glad to get some advice.

Comment: Does XCode not include a watch emulator like for iOS devices?

Comment: yes it does but it does only show your app and does not open maps app or any system app

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info. Pretty hard to develop apps then without an actual device to understand all of the interactions.

Comment: hi @VWGolf2 yesterday i developed one demo of map for watchkit and it is run in simulator.

Comment: @chiragshah I see the map in my app but can't tap it to get to the maps app. Did you be able to open the native maps app?

Comment: in apple map in iWatch there is no iteration provide so you can do any thing on touch

Answer (score 1):

It will open the native Maps app centred on the point where your annotation/marker was, but it won't be displayed. I haven't been able to confirm the behaviour if you have multiple markers, however.

Source: one of the lucky guys/dev forums